# Change javascript file inside running .net core docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

Due to a number of circumstances beyond my control that I cannot change, the task arose to update the java script in the running container. A .net core site is running in the container. I have successfully changed the script in the wwwroot folder, but these changes are not available to clients. I did "docker restart cont_id" and "kill-HUV 1" inside the container, but it didn't help. Can I somehow update the script without stopping the container? Here is the docker file:

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2.4`

`COPY . /app`

`WORKDIR /app`

`ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80`

`EXPOSE 80`

`CMD [ "dotnet", "ххх.WebUi.dll" ]`

Comment: My way: 1. copy js with other name 2. edit index.html to use new js 3. docker restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to `docker build` a new image, `docker stop && docker rm` the existing container, and `docker run` a new container on the new image.  You can rebuild the image while the old container is still running, but there's no way to cause the existing container to somehow "switch" to a different image.

There are a number of options that can only be set when you initially build a container; not just the image to use (and the versions of language runtimes and support libraries embedded in that image) but also port mappings, environment variable settings, volume mounts, and others.  Deleting and recreating a container in this way is extremely routine.  Tools like Docker Compose will let you write the container's settings into a file, so it's straightforward to recreate a container when needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know what to do, but I don't know how. I need a quick and simple temporary solution, and when devops returns, he will already do everything right.